# How to handle multiple question answers in tableau

Tags: sharepoint, tableau-api, power-automate

I have a microsoft form survey where in one of the form questions accepts multiple answers. The answers are delimited by a comma. I run a microsoft power automate to put all the values in the sharepoint list and I pick up the data from tableau list. I want to visualize the frequency of different types of answers
given by the respondents. How do I do that.

The answers are in the form of:

Explosives

Explosives, Wireless

Vehicle, Wireless

Wireless

Factory

Here is the way the answers appear:

[image]

The data from sharepoint lists does not appear like a traditional table. It appears like this:

[image]

How do I visualize the frequency of different answers given by respondents

Comment: Is your problem solved by now?

Comment: yes it is solved